# android intent runs faster than response

Tags: java, php, android, google-maps, android-studio

so i am using volley to read values from the database to my android app, i have a problem when i try to select latitude and longitude from my database, the intent that uses the values i get from the response runs faster than the response actually need to get the selected values from the database, which results in always opening a google maps fragment with locations 0,0.

this is my android code

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener4 =new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success=jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if (success) {
                                lat= jsonResponse.getDouble("lat");
                                lng= jsonResponse.getDouble("lng");
                                System.out.println(lat);
                                System.out.println(lng);
                                Intent i2=new Intent(lists_activity.this,supervisor_maps.class);
                                i2.putExtra("lat",lat);
                                i2.putExtra("lng",lng);
                                startActivity(i2);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(lists_activity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Loading Trucks Failed...")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                UpdatedLocation updatedLocation=new UpdatedLocation(cmp,splitted[1],responseListener4);
                RequestQueue queue=Volley.newRequestQueue(lists_activity.this);
                queue.add(updatedLocation);
```

and this is the class that i should go to and open the location from into the fragment.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(GoogleServiceAvailable())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Perfect!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_maps);
        Intent test=getIntent();
        test.getDoubleExtra("lat",latitude);
        test.getDoubleExtra("lng",longitude);
        System.out.println(latitude);
        System.out.println(longitude);
        initMap();
    }
    else
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.error);
    }
}
public boolean GoogleServiceAvailable()
{
    GoogleApiAvailability api=GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int isAvailable=api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isAvailable== ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvailable))
    {
        Dialog dialog=api.getErrorDialog(this,isAvailable,0);
        dialog.show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cant connect to play services",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}
private void initMap() {
    MapFragment mapFragment= (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    goToLocation(latitude, longitude,15);
}

private void goToLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
    LatLng ll=new LatLng(lat,lng);
    CameraUpdate update= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,zoom);
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title("Your Location."));
}
```

}

of course as you can guess the first 2 system.out do print the location, which in this case is a 30,30 test values but the second system.out in the 2nd class only print 0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing the values into the latitude and longitude variables in the second class.

```
test.getDoubleExtra("lat",latitude);
test.getDoubleExtra("lng",longitude);
```

Should be:

```
latitude = test.getDoubleExtra("lat",0);
longitude = test.getDoubleExtra("lng",0);
```

The way intent.getDoubleExtra works is different than the way getStringExtra works. The second parameter is the "default value". Meaning if the intent does not find a "lat" value, it will use the default value, in this case latitude (which is automatically initialized as 0).

You can write an arbitrary value instead of the 0 I wrote and check if the value is that arbitrary value then there is an error with the intent, so you do something specific instead. Of course this is not a "must" but a suggestion.